# Stack Implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reinventing-the-wheel, stack

I am learning data structures and below is my implementation of a stack in JavaScript. I didn't want to use built in functions for an array because in JavaScript that would be too easy, so I made my own.

```
class Stack {

  constructor(data=null) {
    this.items = [data]
    this.length = 0
  }

  push(data) {
    this.items[this.length] = data
    this.length++
  }

  pop() {
    delete this.items[this.length-1]
    this.length--
  }

  printStack() {
    for(let i = 0; i<this.length; i++)
      console.log(this.items[i])
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return (this.length) > 0 ? false : true
  }

}

let myStack = new Stack();

myStack.push(123)
myStack.push(456)
myStack.pop()

myStack.printStack()

console.log(myStack.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a bug in your constructor:

```
constructor(data=null) {
    this.items = [data]
    this.length = 0
  }
```

If you pass an item and then push to the stack, you lose the first item:

```
let myStack = new Stack("123");
myStack.push("456")
// myStack.items = ["456"]
```

You need to make sure that you initialize length to 1 if an item is passed in. The simplest way to do that is something like this:

```
constructor(datum = null) {
    if (datum !== null) {
        this.items = [datum];
        this.length = 1;
    } else {
        this.items = [];
        this.length = 0;
    }
}
```

Some people like to prefix private fields with `_` to show that they aren't supposed to be used externally. You could consider using [private names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) but they aren't supported everywhere.

Your `pop` function should return the element that was popped from the stack to be useful.

You can also simplify `isEmpty`:

```
isEmpty() {
    return this.length === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

### Encapsulate

The object `Stack` should protect its state as it is easy to add and remove items via the exposed referenced `Stack.items`, or if  `Stack.length` were to be set some erroneous value eg `myStack.length = 1.001`

You can never guarantee your object will act like a stack if you can not trust its state.

### Review

Most points are already covered by accepted answer, however there are some additional points.

- Avoid using `null`
- `Stack.pop` does not return anything? What is the point of a stack that does not provide access to the top item.
- Use getters and setters rather than give direct access to state critical properties.
- Rather than `Stack.printStack`, use a getter to get a copy of the stack that you can then use to log to the console or anything else.
- Spaces between operators. eg `[this.length - 1]` not `[this.length-1]`
- Always delimit code blocks. `for( ; ; )  /* code */` should be `for( ; ; )  { /* code */ }`
- Avoid redundant or long form code.

  You had `delete this.items[this.length-1]; this.length--` could have been a single line `delete this.items[--this.length]`

### Rewrite

The rewrite creates a stack using a factory function. The Stack is frozen to ensure it's state can be trusted.

```js
function Stack(...items) {
    const stack = items;
    return Object.freeze({
        push(...items) { stack.push(...items) },
        pop() { return stack.pop() },
        clear() { stack.length = 0 },
        get size() { return stack.length },
        get isEmpty() { return !stack.length },
        get items() { return [...stack] },
    });         
}


// usage
const myStack = Stack(1, 2, 3);
myStack.push(123, 436, 512);
console.log(myStack.items.join(","));
while (!myStack.isEmpty) { 
    console.log("Pop item[" + (myStack.size - 1) + "]: "  + myStack.pop());
}
```

Comment: THank you! And just to check my knowledge, the returned object has access to the `stack` variable because it forms a closure since `Object.freeze` is a function?

Comment: @JordanBaron It doesn't matter that `Object.freeze` is a function, but that the frozen object contains functions. Each of `push`, `pop`, `clear`, `size`, `isEmpty`, and `items` is a separate closure that has has access to this specific copy of `stack` after being returned.

Comment: @JordanBaron Exactly what @TheRubberDuck commented.  However to clarify terminology. As used in the rewrite `Object.freeze` is a *"function call"*, while the object it freezes contains *"function declarations"* `push`, `pop`, ... . Only function declarations / expressions can close over (closure) variables within scope

Comment: "Avoid redundant or long form code.". Using -- or ++ as part of a larger expression is such an incredibly common cause of errors and confusion that languages worrying about clarity explicitly forbid this.

Comment: @Voo At CodeReview I endeavor to review code at professional level. Wide spread miss understanding of the pre/post decrement/increment operator is not a reason to avoid its use, rather it is a reason to improve education and training. The mind set of "too hard don't use" helps no one and does nothing but hold the industry back.

Comment: @Blindman Well if "least amounts of characters being used" is a good metric for quality of code in your mind, I assume awk and co are your favorite languages ;-) Suffice to say there's been enough bugs in professional code due to this with very little benefit but to each their own.

Comment: @Voo I have never said least characters. The most common metric used to assay code quality is bugs per line. Reducing the number of lines by 20% reduces the number of "bugs" by the same amount. The most effective way to reduce "bugs" in code is to reduce the number of lines of code

Comment: @Blindman Ah I see the problem. When talking about "lines of code" in that context what those papers (yes I know them) mean are *logical lines of code* and not actual physical lines of code. There's a simple thought experiment that should make this clearer: If you simply remove extra newlines (easy to do in languages with statement terminators such as JavaScript) but keep the code identical otherwise this shouldn't change the expected bug count - but yes rather unfortunate naming. Going by "logical lines of code" (i.e. statements) both `i++; foo(i);` and `foo(i++)` are considered identical.

Comment: @voo You are using logical lines of code LLOC rather than physical lines of code LOC.  Using logic lines of code is high problematic for compiled and interpreted languages (what is `i++`, is it `load a, i`, `load b, 1`, `add a,  b`, `store i, a` or just `inc i`, that will depend on the target) LOC holds true in the realm of high level languages as it is the more robust metric by avoiding the vagary of interpretation.

Comment: @Blindman So you really think that putting each part of a for loop on its own line magically triples the likelihood of bugs? (What some code compiles to is irrelevant for logical locs, although obviously how you define a statement/function point/whatever you want to use is open to discussion - but I've never seen a single paper that used assembly instructions for that).

Comment: @Voo Yes 3 lines of code has 3 times the likely hood of bugs than 1 line, but no project is 3 lines long. A typical medium to large project can come in at half a million lines +. Writing tight short form code (as a habit) with rigorous testing (apart reducing time to read and navigate) can reduce line count by 20%, 10000 less lines is substantial. At standard coding rates the savings are 7 figure $

Comment: @Blindman So you really think that the exact same code formatted in different ways will have different bug counts? Well I assume everyone will have to decide for themselves whether that sounds like a reasonable argument to them.

Comment: @Voo Again you are attempting to put words in my mouth. I never said *"formatted"*  I will say *"The same code written in different styles will have different bug counts?  That the number of bugs correlates strongly with the number of line of code."*

Comment: @Blimdman Huh? You yourself said "Yes 3 lines of code has 3 times the likely hood of bugs than 1 line". Which means that if I take that 1 line of code and reformat it to be 3 lines that means the likelihood of bugs increased by a factor of 3 despite it being the same code. That is simply a consequence of using physical lines of code.

Comment: What I imagine your actual argument is, is that physical lines of code are a reasonable proxy for some actually relevant code metric assuming the analyzed code base is large enough. So instead of trying to compute the more complex metric one can approximate its value by using physical loc. This is all fine. The problem arises when you then try to apply that proxy metric on small code snippets and reason based on that.

Comment: @Voo My answer stated *"Avoid redundant or long form code."* My reasoning is in the comments. What you imagine I think is irrelevant . Thanks for the discussion and have a nice day :)